# Detect Combination of keys in datagridview cell

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, winforms

How to detect combination of keys in datagridviewcell in editing mode (Shift + Tab)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is not a [real question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question). Did you try anything to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show their. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: [Check this link, it may help you][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955411/winform-datagridview-handle-tab-and-arrow-keys

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
   private void Main_tab_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   {
         if (e.Shift && (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Down)))
         {
            // do something
         }
   }
```